# I can't scanf a char after number

Tags: c++

My code is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number=0;
    char choice;


    // srand(time(0));

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);


    printf("Character: ");
    scanf("%c",&choice);

}
```

I can type the number but the console shuts down when I want to type the character, what to do?

Comment: I couldnt insert the libraries here but it works. printf shows "Number:" in console and I type my custom number but after I hit enter the console ends without giving me possibility to add the character. I used cout/cin and it worked but printf/scanf doesnt work.. why?

Comment: What *exactly* are you typing? I bet you're typing something other than what you say you're typing.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you meant:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

but your real issue is your

```
scanf("%c",&choice);
```

is reading the newline (enter key) you typed after the number.

So change:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

To:

```
scanf("%d ", &number);   /* note the space after %d */
```

to "suck up" that newline.

More info: most `%something` specifiers in scanf will skip over any leading "whitespace" *(space, tab, newline, etc)* before reading the thing you want it to.  `%c` is an exception to that rule.  Also a space in a scanf format matches any amount of any kind of whitespace.

More more info: many programmers eschew `scanf` in favor of other methods of I/O because of the difficulty in using it effectively and safely.

Comment: An issue every new programmer struggles with when learning to do console IO.

Comment: so I cant scanf a char after i scanned a number? what If I try to programm it through "C" and not c++? I dont understand your code, did you fix anything? or it cant be done?

Comment: NOTE THE SPACE ADDED, then read the "more info" on why that 1 space matters

Comment: @Sick654 He's saying your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do. It reads the number and the character after it, which happens to be a newline. If you want your code to do something else, write code to do what you want. Your code is designed to read "23a" and you are typing "23<enter>a".

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("\n%c",&choice);
```

Add \n as above.